# how do I eliminate duplicatesin sql?

Tags: sql

Can someone point me in the right direction to eliminate duplicates in the student ID field?

```
SQL> select DISTINCT(student_class.student_id) as student_Num,student_class.class_id,
  2  event.event_id, event.event_name
  3  from student_class, event
  4  where student_class.class_id = '10'
  5  and event.class_id = '10';

STUDENT_NUM   CLASS_ID   EVENT_ID EVENT_NAME
----------- ---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
         12         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
         12         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
          9         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
         16         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
          6         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
         18         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
          4         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
          4         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
         16         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
         20         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
          3         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
          2         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
          3         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
          8         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
          9         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
          2         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
          6         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
         20         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
         18         10          2 Flag FOOtball Game
          8         10          5 PICKUP SOCCER GAME
```

Comment: There are duplicates because there are multiple student_id values which match.  What is the expected result?

Comment: When you say 'eliminate duplicates' do you really mean that or rather 'suppress repeating values in the output'?  Because there are no duplicates here if we're using terminology properly. These rows have different values in the event column.

Comment: distinct applies to the whole row.  `distinct(col1)` is not a function on the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY** SQL>

```
  SELECT DISTINCT event.event_id,event.event_name,COUNT(student_class.student_id) AS 'Total Students'
   FROM student_class, event
   WHERE student_class.class_id = '10'
   AND event.class_id = '10' 
     GROUP BY event.event_id,event.event_name,student_class.student_id
```

This should give you the **event id and name**, with the **number** of students that went to it.